# Is there a way to recover element after doing 'rmelem' ?

Tags: clearcase

We performed a rmelem on a softlink (vob element) on doing this it got deleted from integration stream too.

Is there a way using which we can recover/undo the changes especially on the integration stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restore an individual element from backup using the process at:
[IBM: Restoring an element from backup](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_restore_elem.htm)

Comment: Yes, thats what we did. :) Thanks!!